# Function not being bijective but maps A to B and B is subset of A.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

As far as I have understood a function is considered onto if every element of the codomain B is the image of some element of A.

Now what would be the complications in terms of this, if we say that B is a proper subset of A. If f mapping A to B, is it possible that f is an *injective* function but *not onto*, when the $B \subset A$.

I just do not get how this would be possible since every element of B would be in A, so why would this not every element of B be an image of some element of A?

Comment: By example the function that map natural number to powers of 3 is injective if we take domain $\Bbb N$ and codomain $\{n\in\Bbb N : 2\not\mid n\}$.

Comment: In fact, this could be a characterization for infinite sets, i.e a set A is infinite if and only there is a bijection between A and subset B of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functions are possible on any infinite set. Example:
$$f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}-\{1\} \text{ where }f(x)=2x$$
Then $\mathbb{N}-\{1\} \subsetneq \mathbb{N} $ however $f$ is injective and not onto. (as no element is mapped to any odd number)

However such function is not possible in finite sets, which may be why your intuition fails.

Comment: Actually it was the definition, I assumed that in your case 2x would be the my set B. But in fact its all N - {1}, and this would mean that there are some elements of B that are not a image of elements of A. I thought B always was defined by the function.

Comment: Well If you define the range of the function as everything in the codomain (B in your case), then by definition all functions are surjective.

Answer (score 0):

$f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$ be as $f(n)=n+2$

Comment: This is not onto; as we want:  injective not-onto

Answer (score 0):

The *standard* example:

$f: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ given by $f(n) = 2n$. This is injective. If you want $B$ to be proper, you can just do something like:

$f: \Bbb Z \to 2\Bbb Z$ given by $f(n) = 4n$.

Comment: Is this not onto?

Comment: In my first example, 3 is not in the image (nor is any odd integer). In my second example, no odd multiple of 2 is in the image.

Comment: It is onto on $B$ though

Comment: @user64066 what $B$?

Comment: $f:A\to B$ in your case $2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The point being, an injective function $f:A \to B$ need not be onto, even if $B \subset A$ However, for this to be true, we need an infinite set, $A$.